# How can I autogenerate SDL schema of GraphQL for any API explorer?

Tags: go, graphql

Given an API explorer (e.g., [*Google APIs Explorer*](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/)), how can one autogenerate [SDL (Schema Definition Language)](http://graphql.org/learn/schema/) schema for all of the queries?

More specifically, I'm interested in doing it in a golang using [gqlgen](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen).

*Some context*: I'm interested in using GraphQL and would like to find out whether it's possible to generate SDL schema automatically (right now, I *convert* it manually which doesn't look right).